# Restart a scenario from the task it fails automatically

Tags: sql, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODI , and I have a single mapping and a scenario for that , how can I restart the scenario from the same point after it fails due to some issue automatically.
For ex if I have around 100 rows and 90 gets inserted and after that server shuts down or some reason it stops how can I restart the scenario from the same point without having to start from the starting of the scenario and insert remaining 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this to restart the session from where it failed.

[ODI Session Restart - Scenarios & Load Plans](http://odi-ee.blogspot.com/2011/05/odi-session-restart-scenarios-load.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if there is a way to do what you asked but, you can try to make a procedure using Fetch, create a variable that gets the number of rows that were already inserted and then when is restarts u can continue from beyond that point.

SELECT val
FROM   rownum_order_test
ORDER BY val
OFFSET variable_rows ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

or create a status for each insert, after the insert change the status 1 to 2, and then when you restart only insert the ones with status 1